# Did Solo ever face any repercussions as a deserter from the Empire?

Tags: star-wars, han-solo, solo-a-star-wars-story

Han formerly being a part of the Imperial military has long been part of the extended universe of Star Wars. With the release of Solo: A Star Wars Story, it was established in Disney canon that Solo deserted from the Imperial Army while he was assigned to Minban. In that film, it is even mentioned that hunting down a single deserter is not a priority for the Empire, but that doesn't mean that they *never* do it or would not take action if they happened to cross paths with a deserter.

In Disney canon, does Han ever face any particular repercussions after his escape from Minban from his status as a deserter? He is captured by the Empire at least twice later in his life (on Bespin and the moon of Endor), but I don't recall any particular mention of any specific punishment for desertion or even any hint that the Imperial forces there even *recognize* that he is a deserter or consider him anything other than "Rebel Scum" and (on Bespin) someone with a bounty on him by Jabba the Hutt.

Comment: Presumably by the time of his two captures in the OT the fact he was a deserter didn't really matter much as the other things took precedence. And note he was boarded and searched before ANH as a smuggler so if anything would have happened it would have happened before the OT.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot that's right, that's why I'm asking this question. It seems that the Empire basically doesn't care, and may *not even recognize* that the Solo that they encounter was once one of them (and not some random nobody who never wore an Imperial uniform). The question is if they ever made the connection in some way and used that information in some, perhaps minor, way.

Comment: He faces the repercussions in _Solo: A Star Wars Story_ itself, or the initial ones at least when Beckett has him thrown in with Chewie.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot perhaps, but I'm asking about later in his life. Obviously, deserting can be hard and sometimes violent, but the question is if the Empire took any action to try to hunt him down or even recognized that the "Rebel" they were dealing with later was in fact a deserted Imperial trooper.

Comment: Sure, just thought it was worth pointing out that he was captured initially for being a deserter so maybe the later "desertion" didn't count as actual desertion.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot thanks. I suppose the initial capture is obvious, and also part of his actual *process* of deserting. Being captured in the act is different than being actively hunted down months or years later by some Imperial Anti-Desertion Enforcement Unit or being assigned to worse-than-usual prison camp conditions ten years later because his file is annotated "Rebel Scum" *and* "Imperial Deserter".

Comment: Point of interest: in *Empire Strikes Back*, Vader isn't interested in turning Han over to the usual Imperial authorities for desertion *or* rebellion - once he used Han to get Luke, he was fine kicking him over to Fett. Unless he figured dealing with Jabba was a worse fate than an Imperial prison...

Comment: By the time of ANH, the Empire's been around for what, c.20 years?  So most people of military age with military experience will necessarily be ex-Imperial.  The Empire may simply consider "Rebel" as approximately synonymous with "deserter" and not feel the need to distinguish beyond that.

Comment: Don't forget that at the time these captures were filmed (1980/83) there was hardly any story at all that was canon besides the three movies, and the movies don't give any hint that Han has ever served in imperial forces. I read a lot of (at that time canon) SW-stories in the 90s and early 2000s and vaguely remember that somewher it was mentioned that he was in military service but was discharged dishonorably. However, that is decades ago, so I might be wrong here.

Answer (score 4):

It's not especially clear if the Empire were even *aware* of his continued existence. He was in the Imperial army under an assumed name and the last time they saw him, he was being thrown into a pit on Mimban to be executed. The pit itself [collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlvKI.png) and several soldiers were buried under tons of metal plates and mud.

It's certainly possible that his absence wasn't noted and that he was never marked down as an escapee/deserter, which would explain why Vader was happy to hand Solo over to Fett rather than delivering him up to Imperial justice.